# clever way to conditionally split this string?

Tags: php, parsing, string

I've got a string that could be in one of two forms:

```
prefix=key=value (which could have any characters, including '=')
```

or

```
key=value
```

So I need to split it either on the first or second equals sign, based on a boolean that gets set elsewhere. I'm doing this:

```
if ($split_on_second) {
    $parts = explode('=', $str, 3);
    $key = $parts[0] . '=' . $parts[1];
    $val = $parts[2];
} else {
    $parts = explode('=', $str, 2);
    $key = $parts[0];
    $val = $parts[1];
}
```

Which should work, but feels inelegant. Got any better ideas in php? (I imagine there's a regex-ninja way to do it, but I'm not a regex-ninja.;-)

Comment: Using regex would result in two problems.

Comment: OT: If `value` can have `=` in it, the `$val` assignment seems wrong...

Comment: Are you stuck with using "prefix=key=vale"?  If you have the option, changing things to be "prefix:key=value" and "key=value" would make your life much more simple.

Comment: yes I'm stuck with that form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about just

```
$parts = explode('=', $str);
$key = array_shift( $parts);
//additionally, shift off the second part of the key
if($split_on_second)
{
    $key = $key . '=' . array_shift($parts);
}
//recombine any accidentally split parts of the value.
$val = implode($parts, "=");
```

Another variation

```
$explodeLimit = 2;
if($split_on_second)
{
    $explodeLimit++;
}
$parts = explode('=', $str, $explodeLimit);
//the val is what's left at the end
$val = array_pop($parts);
//recombine a split key if necessary
$key = implode($parts, "=");
```

And haven't tested this, but seems like it could be one of those fun optimizations that make code accurate but unreadable...

```
$explodeLimit = 2;
//when split_on_second is true, it bumps the value up to 3
$parts = explode('=', $str, $explodeLimit + $split_on_second );
//the val is what's left at the end
$val = array_pop($parts);
//recombine a split key if necessary
$key = implode($parts, "=");
```

Comment: your optimization scares me. :) what if $split_on_second = 3? (In theory, it should be a strict bool, but with php, you never know. I suppose you could cast it to be sure.) I'd probably optimize it with `$explodeLimit = ($split_on_second) ? 3 : 2`, though.

Comment: I know, that C style true/false stuff is crazy exploitable, right! It scares me to, but so do handgrenades, and the army still uses those!

Answer (score 5):

### Edit:

Now I notice that you're getting the "if prefix should be there or not" from somewhere else, in which case my original solution is probably a bit less elegant. Instead, what I'd suggest is something like this:

```
$parts = explode('=', $str);
$key = array_shift($parts);
if($has_prefix) {
    $key .= '=' . array_shift($parts);
}
$val = implode('=', $parts);
```

.

#### My original response:

```
$parts = array_reverse(explode('=', $str));
$val = array_shift($parts);
$key = implode('=', array_reverse($parts));
```

Comment: @Amber Beat me to it! +1 for speed

Comment: Actually, I need to modify it slightly, since the $key part would be reversed atm. Edit: Fixed now.

Comment: seems like this would ignore the case where $value contains an = sign

Comment: Yeah Zak, I just saw that as well. So I edited my answer to add another version that works for the external flag bit. (Edit: Seems you had the same idea as I did on my edit. :))

Comment: Gave Zak the check, since he came up with two ideas, but +1 for you, too. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($prefix_exists) {
    list($prefix, $str) = explode('=', $str, 2);
    $prefix .= '=';
}

list($key, $val) = explode('=', $str, 2);
$key = $prefix . $key;
```

Comment: This variation doesn't seem to recombine the prefix and (sub)key